# Use node serial port and AT commands to send sms

Tags: node.js, serial-port, at-command

I am using nodejs and [serial-port](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialport) npm package to connect my smartphone via the com port. I am sending sms using AT commands. The problem I am facing is that it only send sms when there is no empty character in the string. e.g "myTest" will be sent but "my Test" does not get sent and gives error. Here is my code.

```
const SerialPort = require('serialport');
const serialPort = new SerialPort('myComPort');

serialPort.on('open', () => {
 serialPort.write('AT+CMGF=1\r'); // set SMS text mode
 serialPort.write('AT+CMGS="02122323232"\r'); // send sms message
 serialPort.write('my' + ' ' +String.fromCharCode(26)+'Test' + ' '+ String.fromCharCode(26)+'STring\r\n');
 serialPort.write('\x1A');
 serialPort.write('^z'); 
});
```

How I can send string with spaces as sms.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it in heperterm app or something like? Other I think all lines must finished not '\r' but '\r\n'

```
const SerialPort = require('serialport');
const serialPort = new SerialPort('myComPort');

serialPort.on('open', () => {
 serialPort.write('AT+CMGF=1\r\n'); // set SMS text mode
 serialPort.write('AT+CMGS="02122323232"\r\n'); // send sms message
 serialPort.write('my Test STring\r\n');
 serialPort.write('\x1A');
 serialPort.write('^z'); 
});
```

Comment: I have no idea about heperterm app or anything like that. I just want to send some data from my front-end mean stack app to the backend so that the text message could be sent.

Comment: I will try your solution and will comment again.

Comment: unfortunately it still does not send it. It is sending only when there is no space in between the string.

Comment: what if change space to \x20?

Comment: I changed the space to \x20 but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The question text here is a bit different, but the code is virtual identical with the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57298140/23118), and all the same issues apply so all of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313924/23118) applies as well.

The differences are that you are correctly terminating the command line with just `\r` (excellent), and you should use `String.fromCharCode(26)` to create the escape character.

Comment: I have used it as follows 
serialPort.write('my test string'+String.fromCharCode(26)+'\r\n');
It still does not work :(

Comment: But did you also fix all the other issues?

Comment: yes of course. My only problem is that I cannot send a string with spaces. other than that, the text message is sent.

Comment: @Chasmatu Could you update the question with the new code then?

Comment: I updated the code. Could you please review it again. Thanks. Please bare with me as I am novice in AT commands.

Comment: @Chasmatu I mean [update this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57215371/edit) with your new code.

Comment: @Chasmatu You have not added code to **read and parse** the response lines from the modem nor have you added code to wait for the "ready to receive payload" prompt from the modem. This is what I meant by asking if you had fixed all the other issues (outside of fromCharCode), which still is missing. Information for how to do this is provided in my linked answer.